# Solving Vector Equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> $2$. a: For what vectors $$v = \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{pmatrix}$$ does the equation $Ax = v$ have a solution if $$A = \left(\begin{array}{crc}
> 1 & 0 & 1 \\
> 0 & -1 & 2 \\
> 1 & -1 & 3 
> \end{array}\right),\quad
> \text{ and }\quad x = \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}.$$

I'm confused about this question. I would know how to solve it if the components of $x$ were constants, but I don't know how it works when there are two unknown vectors like this.

Comment: You mean, "if the components of $v$ were constants", rather than the components of $x$, right?

Comment: The way I'm thinking of the question, I meant what I said. I don't know if I'm trying to do it the right way though.

Comment: That would not correspond to solving an equation; it would correspond to plugging in values and finding the answer, which is a very different thing. Did you cover "solving systems of linear equations" at some point in your linear algebra course? $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the *unknowns*. If $a,b,c$ were specific numbers, then the equation $Ax=v$ corresponds to a system of 3 linear equations in three unknowns, and it has "a solution" if the system has a solution. They are asking you to find *all* triples of values of $a,b,c$ for which the corresponding system of linear equations has a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Added.** Okay, let's clarify this, since you express confusion. If we multiply out $Ax$ and set it equal to $v$, we get:
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1 + x_3 \\
-x_2 + 2x_3\\
x_1 - x_2 + 3x_3
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\end{array}\right),$$
which leads to the system of linear equations in three unknowns:
$$\begin{array}{rcccccl}
x_1 &   &    &  + & x_3 & = & a\\
    & - & x_2 & + & 2x_3 & = & b\\
x_1 & - & x_2 & + & 3x_3 & = & c
\end{array}$$

The question is: for what vectors $v$ does this system have a solution $x$?

For example, if
$$v =\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\0\end{array}\right)$$
then the system has a solution (namely, $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$). If 
$$v = \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\3\end{array}\right)$$
then the system has a solution (for example, $x_1 = 1$, $x_2=-2$, $x_3=0$; or $x_1=0$, $x_2=0$, $x_3=3$; or any of a number of others, but at least one). On the other hand, if
$$v=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\0\end{array}\right)$$
then the system has no solutions: from $x_1+x_3=0$ we get $x_1=-x_3$. Substituting into the third equation, we would get $-x_2 + 2x_3 = 0$, so $x_2 = 2x_3$; but if we substitute that into the second equation, we get $-2x_3+2x_3 = 1$, which is impossible. So for *this* $v$, there are no solutions.

So... for *some* choices of $v$, the system has a solution. For *other* choices of $v$, the system has *no* solutions.

The question is: what are the choices of $v$ that will give you a system with a solution?

---

You are being asked to find the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ for which the system
$$\begin{array}{rcccccl}
x_1 &   &    &  + & x_3 & = & a\\
    & - & x_2 & + & 2x_3 & = & b\\
x_1 & - & x_2 & + & 3x_3 & = & c
\end{array}$$
has a solution. I hope you are familiar with solving systems of equations by Gaussian elimination, because that is what I'm going to do next. The augmented matrix of this system is just:
$$\left(\begin{array}{crr|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & a\\
0 & -1 & 2 & b\\
1 & -1 & 3 & c
\end{array}\right)$$
(that is, it is nothing more than $(A|v)$). We need to know when this system is consistent. If $a$, $b$, and $c$ were numbers, then Gaussian elimination is a recipe that tells us how to figure that out.

So then let's pretend they *are* specific numbers, and see where that leads us! We subtract the first row from the third row, and we obtain
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & a\\
0 & -1 & 2 & b\\
0 & -1 & 2 & c-a
\end{array}\right).$$
And now, subtracting the second row from the third row, we get
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & a\\
0 & -1 & 2 & b\\
0 & 0 & 0 & c-a-b
\end{array}\right).$$

Now... under what conditions would  you know this system has *no* solutions? Under what conditions will it *certainly* have solutions?

Comment: I'm confused, where does the vector x fit into all of this?

Comment: It is *not* there, don't you know this technique when $a$, $b$ and $c$ are numbers? If you don't, perhaps your confusion comes from there..

Comment: If you multiply out $Ax=v$ and write it out as equations, you get $$\begin{array}{rcccccl} 1x_1 & + & 0x_2 & + & 1x_3 &=&a\\ 0x_1 & - & 1x_2 & + & 2x_3 & = & b\\1x_1 & - & 1x_2 & + & 3x_3 & = & c\end{array}$$ If you try to solve the system by Gaussian elimination, you will simply get back to the matrix I start with.

Comment: I'm still not clear on where the x1,x2,x3's go...

Comment: @StickFigs: I've added stuff at the beginning; hopefully this helps.

Comment: Oh ok so for $\left(\begin{array}{crr|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & a\\
0 & -1 & 2 & b\\
1 & -1 & 3 & c
\end{array}\right)$ basically the names of the first 3 columns would be x1,x2,x3, respectively?

Comment: @StickFigs: If you like naming columns of matrices, sure; they are the columns that correspond to those variables.